# Is this the correct way to translate this formula into CN prenex form?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

Is this the correct way to solve the following problem?

$$(∀x ∃y P( x, g (y, f(x)) ∨ ¬Q(z))) ∨ ¬∀x R(x,y)$$

1. Import the negation.

$$(∀x ∃y P( x, g (y, f(x)) ∨ ¬Q(z))) ∨ ∃x ¬R(x,y)$$

2. Substitute the x in R(x,y) to u,  Substitute the y in R(x,y) to w

$$(∀x ∃y P( x, g (y, f(x)) ∨ ¬Q(z))) ∨ ∃u ¬R(u,w)$$

3. Since there are no free occurrences of x and y, take out there quantifiers.

$$∀x ∃y (P( x, g (y, f(x)) ∨ ¬Q(z))) ∨ ∃u ¬R(u,w)$$

4. Since there are no free occurrences of u, take out its quantifiers.

$$∀x ∃y ∃u(P( x, g (y, f(x)) ∨ ¬Q(z))) ∨ ¬R(u,w)$$

5. Rearrange ()'s

$$∀x ∃y ∃u (P( x, g (y, f(x)) ∨ ¬Q(z) ∨ ¬R(u,w))$$

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Perfect! Good job!

Comment: You should rename bound variables, not free variables.

Comment: @FabioSomenzi Is there any reason why we should rename bound variables and not free variables?

Comment: Because you start with a formula in which there's a free variable $y$, and you want to end with a formula in which there's the same free variable.  While renaming variables produces an equisatisfiable formula, what if you need to use this formula in conjunction with other formulae?  Renaming bound variables frees you completely from this type of concerns.  It's fully general, and it's therefore the algorithmic (as opposed to *ad hoc*) way of doing things.

Comment: Oh, so you're saying if I had another a predicate which had a free variable y. Then, if I wanted to rename the free variables I will have to rename 2 variables instead of just the bound one?

Comment: Yes.  Bound variables are local.  You can rename them freely.  Free variables are global.  You have to watch out.  Why bother?  You can always rename the occurrences of bound variables and leave the free occurrences alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perfect, except for parenthesis:

$$∀x ∃y \color{red}{(}P( x, g (y, f(x))\color{red}{)} ∨ ¬Q(z)) ∨ ¬∀x R(x,y)$$

1. Import the negation.

$$∀x ∃y (P( x, g (y, f(x))) ∨ ¬Q(z)) ∨ ∃x ¬R(x,y)$$

2. Rename bound variables: Change the second x to u,  change the second y in to w

$$∀x ∃y (P( x, g (y, f(x))) ∨ ¬Q(z)) ∨ ∃u ¬R(u,w)$$

3. Since there are no free occurrences of x and y $\color{red}{in ∃u ¬R(u,w)}$, take out $\color{red}{their}$ quantifiers.

$$∀x ∃y ((P( x, g (y, f(x))) ∨ ¬Q(z)) ∨ ∃u ¬R(u,w))$$

4. Since there are no free occurrences of u $\color{red}{in (P( x, g (y, f(x))) ∨ ¬Q(z))}$, take out its quantifiers.

$$∀x ∃y ∃u((P( x, g (y, f(x))) ∨ ¬Q(z)) ∨ ¬R(u,w))$$

5. Rearrange ()'s

$$∀x ∃y ∃u (P( x, g (y, f(x))) ∨ ¬Q(z) ∨ ¬R(u,w))$$

Comment: Good eye!  The problem seems to start with $P$.  In all likelihood, it should be $P(x,g(y,f(x)))$.

Comment: @FabioSomenzi Yes, just spotted that myself .. So in fact there are several parentheses missing

Comment: Oh, my bad. I forgot to type those ()'s. Thank you for catching that!

Comment: At the risk of sounding insistent, I'll insist that in step 2 it's the bound $y$ that should be renamed.

Comment: @FabioSomenzi How about now?

Comment: @name OK, I think I got all the parentheses correct now ...

Comment: @Bram28 Yeah, I messed up pretty bad when it came to the parentheses, but at the very least the way I did it was fine which is what I was really worried about. Thanks for your help!

Comment: In step 2, I'd say $\forall x\, \exists w(P(x,g(w,f(x))) \vee \neg Q(z)) \vee \exists u \,\neg R(u,y)$.  Other than that, I can't spot any mismatched parentheses and the explanations of the steps are also spot on.

Comment: @FabioSomenzi Wow, good catch!